# SQLException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, tcp

when I run a JDBC connection I get the following exception: "SQLException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed."

I read many answers to similar questions, I have enabled named pipes and TCP/IP and I have set port number in IPAII to 1433. However, I still get this message. 
Please help!!

My code:

```
    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://SQLFULL:1433;databaseName=BA_ELTRUN;";
    Connection dbcon = null;

    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    }
    catch(java.lang.ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.print("ClassNotFoundException: ");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    try
    {
        dbcon = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"username","password");
    }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
        errorMessages = "Could not close connection with the Database Server: <br>"
                        + e.getMessage();
                        throw new SQLException(errorMessages);
    }
```

Comment: do netstat -a and see if 1433 is bound (look for a line with LISTEN on port 1433)

Comment: @Jan I can't find this line you mentioned.

Comment: Sorry - `netstat -na` does numeric output

Comment: You could also `telnet SQLFULL 1433` to check for the port bound

Comment: @Jan Telnet: Could not open connection to the host on port 1433 : connect failed

Comment: That confirms your sqlserver is not configured to listen on tcp - check your sqlserver configuration and restart database services

Comment: @Jan I checked that, port number in IPAII is 1433 and I have restarted the database services. What else should I do?

Comment: @Jan And TCP is enabled

Comment: Also check http://stackoverflow.com/a/34693249/643500