# The TCP/IP connection to the host, port 1433 has failed

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, tcp

I am new to JDBC connections and I am very confused. I have enable TCP/IP and Named Pipes and in TCP/IP -> IP Adresses I have set TCP port to 1433 and I have restarted the server. I have also open access to SQL Server via Windows Firewall with Advanced Security. The problem is that I still get this error:

> SQLException: The TCP/IP connection to the host MSSQL$SQLFULL, port
>   1433 has failed. Error: "null. Verify the connection properties, check
>   that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting
>   TCP/IP connections at the port, and that no firewall is blocking TCP
>   connections to the port."

I run on cmd the following: `telnet SQLFULL 1433` and I get this message:
Could not open connection to the host on port 1433 : connect failed

My code:

```
String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://MSSQL$SQLFULL:1433;databaseName=BA_ELTRUN;";
Connection dbcon = null;
String errorMessages = "";

try
{
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
}
catch(java.lang.ClassNotFoundException e)
{
    System.out.print("ClassNotFoundException: ");
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}

try
{
    dbcon = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"username","password");
}
catch(SQLException e)
{
     System.out.print("SQLException: ");
     System.out.println(e.getMessage());
     errorMessages = "Could not close connection with the Database Server: <br>"
                    + e.getMessage();
                    throw new SQLException(errorMessages);
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is this your host 'MSSQL$SQLFULL'?  More information is needed.  Show the code and the DB setup.

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb I add my code. MSSQL$SQLFULL is in "log on as" field in SQL Server Configuration Management. In field Name it is: SQL Server (SQLFULL)

Comment: Change that value to the 'Server Name' of the login of the MS SQL Server Management.  Also, the error message should indicate that a connection could not be opened instead of could not close.

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb It is .\SQLFULL but this "\" is not accepted from compiler. I get the message "illegal escape character". I tried "SQLFULL" but I still get this message "SQLException: The TCP/IP connection to the host SQLFULL, port 1433 has failed. Error: "null. Verify the connection properties, check that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port, and that no firewall is blocking TCP connections to the port."."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an exact duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34689149/2144390).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Connection Strings - dot(".") or "(local)" or "(localdb)"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20217518/sql-server-connection-strings-dot-or-local-or-localdb)

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb do you think that there is a connection problem because of the name I give? But which is the correct one? Sorry if this is a stupid question but I am new to this and I really don't know what else can I do to fix this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copy computer name :`cmd.exe -> hostname`

or

`Right Click on Start then click on System and copy the Computer Name`

URL should be:

```
String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://<Computer Name>\\SQLFULL:1433;databaseName=BA_ELTRUN;";

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"<user>","<password>"):
```

Comment: I was stumbling on this for more than a day and it did not strike me that there has to be two "\\" because one is an escape sequence. Thank you!

Comment: @RGV, glad this answer helped